# What is vm in virtualBox used for

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

I Downloaded and installed `Genymotion` yesterday it also have `virtualBox` I followed the **Genymotion Tutorial** and successfully created a device to test android apps. I also tested 2 of my apps in it successfully **But** I want to know

- What actually `virtualBox` is ?
- what `VM` is?

and

- what they are used for ?
  **Edit:**
  **I tested apps without creating `VM` if it is not necessary then Why `Genymotion` have this option.** I want to know what's their purpose is because these apps can be tested without these as I mentioned above.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a VM is a virtual machine. In simple words, it is virtual hardware(emulator) to run your virtual devices.

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine):

> In computing, a virtual machine (VM) is an emulation of a particular
>   computer system. Virtual machines operate based on the computer
>   architecture and functions of a real or hypothetical computer, and
>   their implementations may involve specialized hardware, software, or a
>   combination of both.

one more [reference](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/virtual-machine)

> A virtual machine (VM) is an operating system OS or application
>   environment that is installed on software which imitates dedicated
>   hardware. The end user has the same experience on a virtual machine as
>   they would have on dedicated hardware.

[Virtual box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) is tool provided by Oracle to create virtual machines:

> Oracle VM VirtualBox (formerly Sun VirtualBox, Sun xVM VirtualBox and
>   Innotek VirtualBox) is a hypervisor for x86 computers from Oracle
>   Corporation. Developed initially by Innotek GmbH, it was acquired by
>   Sun Microsystems in 2008 which was in turn acquired by Oracle in 2010.
>
> VirtualBox may be installed on a number of host operating systems,
>   including: Linux, OS X, Windows Vista, Solaris, and OpenSolaris. There
>   are also ports to FreeBSD and Genode.
>
> It supports the creation and management of guest virtual machines
>   running versions and derivations of Windows, Linux, BSD, OS/2,
>   Solaris, Haiku, OSx86 and others, and limited virtualization of OS
>   X guests on Apple hardware.

and finally they are used to emulate the virtual devices you need.